Issue with VAE Model - KerasTensor Incompatibility with TensorFlow Functions
Spark version 3.4.0
Python 3.9.16
tensorflow 2.17.0
I encountered an issue while building a VAE (Variational Autoencoder) model using the following configuration: I am doing this work as part of imputation of fraud data
Input dimension: 250
Latent dimension: 32

Method name: build_vae_model
This error occurred when calling build_vae_model within the impute_data_vae module, leading to a failure with the following error description:
Error:
A KerasTensor cannot be used as input to a TensorFlow function. A KerasTensor is a symbolic placeholder for a shape and dtype, used when constructing Keras Functional models or Keras Functions. You can only use it as input to a Keras layer or a Keras operation (from the namespaces `keras.layers` and `keras.operations`). You are likely doing something like:

```

x = Input(...)

...

tf_fn(x)  # Invalid.

```

What you should do instead is wrap `tf_fn` in a layer:

```
class MyLayer(Layer):

    def call(self, x):

        return tf_fn(x)
x = MyLayer()(x)
```

As a next step, I will be adjusting the build_vae_model method to wrap the TensorFlow function(s) inside appropriate Keras layers. It is becoming very time consuming. If anyone has faced a similar issue or has recommendations on the best practices for handling, I will appreciate it.
Further investigation
The error was caused by directly applying TensorFlow operations (tf.shape and tf.random.normal) to Keras tensors (z_mean, z_log_var), which Keras does not allow. The solution, as indicated by the error message, is to encapsulate these operations inside a Keras layer. I implemented a custom Sampling layer as follows:
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

class Sampling(Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

I then integrated this layer into the VAE model to perform the sampling. This approach resolved the error, as it ensures that the operations are part of the Keras model pipeline.

Please show the code that causes this error. Also the error message is giving you quite precise instructions of what you are doing wrong and how to solve this. If this does not match your situtation, explain why and how, and show relevant code

Already resolved. see the explanation under "further investigation" in the main body
